# Oozie fs:exists() doesn't work for amzon s3 buckets?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, oozie

I am trying to check in a decision node of oozie, if a file is existing in amazon s3. for that i am trying to use in decision node, fs:exists(S3://path) function. But it is not working. Any suggestions how to achieve this. Badly in need of guidance.

Comment: Refer to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-426 for details. It looks like its an open issue in OOzie JIRA board.

Comment: I had to rely on shellaction to acheive this. amazon S3 is not a FileSystem, so fs:exists() doesnt work for S3. By default fs:exists() function extends FileSystem Class, therefore it is restricted to hdfs only.